# Django views and templates and static html

Tags: django, templates, view

I want to fabricate some HTML inside my view and then have it rendered in my template.  What I see rendered is `<div>xyz</div>` and I just want to see `xyz`.  What am I doing wrong?

My template snippet:

```
{{ normalized }}
```

My view snippet:

```
context["normalized"] = "<div>xyz</div>"
template_name = "demo.html"
return render(request, template_name, context)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**`safe`**--(Django doc)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#safe) filter

```
{{ normalized|safe }}
```

Comment: This worked great except for the fact that it also rendered my styling moot.  My real html looks more like this:  <div class="myclass">xyz</div>

Comment: I dont see any problem with that, https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlWNq.png

Comment: I can see all my styling in the debug window  - just appears to have no effect